# Finding probability that chess Knight will stay on chessboard after k moves with dynamic prgramming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was trying out ["Knight Probability in Chessboard" problem from leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/knight-probability-in-chessboard/):

> Given `n`, `k`, `row` and `column`, we have to find the probability that knight initially kept at  cell indexed by `[row,column]` will stay on `n x n` chessboard after `k` moves.

I wanted to do it by addition, that is, maintain number of ways we can get to cell at index `[x,y]` in `k`th step at dynamic programming memory location indexed `[x,y,k]`. Then sum counts in all cells at `k`th index and then divide it by `8^k`. That is, if I start at index `[0,0]`, with `n=4`, the values at successive k-th index will be:

**After step 1:**

```
0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0
0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
```

**After step 2:**

```
4   0   2   0
0   0   0   2
2   0   0   0
0   2   0   4
```

**After step 3:**

```
0   6   0   0
6   0   11  0
0   11  0   6
0   0   6   0
```

Only first step output seems to be correct. After second step, the sum is 2+2+2+2+4+4=16 and the probability is 16/8^2 = 0.25. However, the actual answer is 0.125. After third step, the sum becomes 6+6+6+6+11+11=46 and the probability is 46/8^3 = 0.0898. But, the actual answer is 0.039. Where does this dynamic programming approach make mistake?

**Sample calculation for step 2**

[image]

Comment: In step two, why are all values doubled? There will be 2 ways to reach `0,0` after 2 moves, not 4

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I have updated the question and added the calculation example at the end. Let me know if udnerstandable.

Comment: It's still not clear why each move is contributing 2 instead of 1

Comment: After step 2 seems to be wrong. You should get 2 where you have 4 and 1 where you have 2. Then in step 3 you should have 2 where you have 6 and 6 where you have 11. So you get (4 * 6 + 2 * 2) / 8^3 = 0.0547

Comment: Yes I was incorrectly incrementing the count. All I had to do it to carry forward them as going from one cell to another cell still represents the same single path to next cell and does not create two different paths to next cell.

Answer (score 1):

Bottom up approach:

Start by filling P(x_start, y_start, 0) = 1 and setting (x_start, y_start) in a map (from positions to booleans) `previous_layer_map`. Also, set the counter `current_layer` to 1.

Iterate though each of the n^2 positions of the board. For each of them, check in O(1) if it reaches a square in `previous_layer_map`. If so:

If (x, y) was never saw before in the current layer (current_layer_map[x][y] == false), fill

P(x, y, current_layer) = P(x_reached, y_reached, current_layer-1)/8

and set (x, y) in `current_layer_map`.

Else, set

P(x, y, current_layer) += P(x_reached, y_reached, current_layer-1)/8

After you finish iterating though each of the n^2 positions of the board, empty `previous_layer_map`, fill it with the elements of `current_layer_map` and empty `current_layer_map`. Also, increase the counter `current_layer`. Then, start a new iteration. Go like this until you reach the k-th layer.

Total time complexity: O(k * n^2).

Comment: I want to do it (bottom up) "by counting possible number of valid cells at each step" and calculating probability at the end ... "not by calculating probabilities at each step". I have already solved this problem by successively calculating probabilities.

Comment: In algorithmic terms, it's equivalent to the bottom up approach I described. The numbers you want to put in your cells are the numerators of the probabilities I get in my answer at each step. For example, in the second step, it's not 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 4 + 4 but 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 2

Comment: Just remove the division by 8 from my answer and you will get the numbers you want in the right way.

Comment: Aah, this was on the spot. Though obvious, dont know how it didnt click to me. It helped me to get where I was making the mistake. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Top down approach:

Let P(x, y, k) be the probability that the knight is at the square (x, y) at the k-th step. Look at all squares that the knight could have come from (you can get them in O(1), just look at the board with a pen and paper and get the formulas from the different cases, like knight in the corner, knight in the border, knight in a central region etc). Let them be (x1, y1), ... (xj, yj). For each of these squares, what is the probability that the knight jumps to (x, y) ? Considering that it can go out of the border, it's always 1/8. So:

P(x, y, k) = (P(x1, y1, k-1) + ... + P(xj, yj, k-1))/8

The base case is k = 0.

P(x, y ,0) = 1 if (x, y) = (x_start, y_start) and P(x, y, 0) = 0 otherwise.

That is your recurrence formula. You can use dynamic programming to calculate it.

Open question: how to analyze the time complexity of this solution ? Is it equivalent to the bottom-up approach described in my other answer ?

Comment: I know I can solve this problem by computing probablities in successive steps. But I want to try it out by counting possible number of valid cells in successive steps and then computing final probability at the last step as valid steps / all possible steps.

Comment: I see. You want the bottom up approach. I will describe it in another answer. But I will keep the top down approach here for reference as I believe it's more intuitive

Answer (score 0):

I was incorrecty incrementing the numbers. For example in the diagram shown at the end of original question, red arrows increments from 1 to 2. It shouldnt be the case as going from one cell to next represents the same single path to next cell. It does not create two different paths to next cell. Same is the case with blue arrow. So, corrected steps are:

**After step 1**

```
0   0   0   0   
0   0   1   0   
0   1   0   0   
0   0   0   0
```

**After step 2**

```
2   0   1   0   
0   0   0   1   
1   0   0   0   
0   1   0   2
```

**After step 3**

```
0   2   0   0   
2   0   6   0   
0   6   0   2   
0   0   2   0
```

and (2+2+2+2+6+6)/8^3 = 20/8^3 = 0.039
which is the correct answer!